# Have hearts replaced star ratings in iOS 8.4 with Apple Music/iTunes Match?

Tags: ios, itunes, music, itunes-match, apple-music

I have been rating songs for a VERY long time, have several playlists using star ratings, etc.

You used to be able to click on an album and 'flip' it in iOS and could see the ratings of your music. This seems to be completely gone, and only have the option to 'heart' the item. Is there a way to edit the star rating of a song on iOS 8.4?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No - the controls are moved, though.

Click the song title in the now playing screen, it will change to a set of stars where you can see and change star ratings.

Comment: That worked! Had me worried that these years of organization were gone!

Comment: Anyone else noticed that a lot of their 'star' ratings were reset (to empty/no rating) after upgrading to iOS 8.4?

Comment: I too am a star rating maniac and had to re-learn how to set ratings vs. the new heart. Also found this great article on how to get your playlists to display more prominently, worked like a charm:
http://www.macrumors.com/2015/07/01/replace-connect-with-playlists-apple-music/ I also noticed that a number of my songs had ratings wiped out, it appears to be songs added in the last month or so. Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: @sxc731No, but feel free to ask a new question and link here if you think something is going on.

Comment: @bmike I think I know what's going on; it's to do with the iCloud Music library, a side-effect of Apple Music which I wasn't using before.  There appear to be MAJOR concerns with this feature, namely:

Comment: @bmike (cont'd): 
1) Your iTunes library can get corrupted (this is what I'm observing with *many* of my ratings having been wiped out)
2) Many songs that were ripped from CD or even some purchased from iTunes can get replaced with DRM'ed versions!
Yikes! [The Real Difference Between iTunes Match and iCloud Music Library: DRM](http://www.mcelhearn.com/the-real-difference-between-itunes-match-and-icloud-music-library-drm/)

Answer (score 8):

I just went into Preferences > General Ratings in iTunes 12.2, OS Yosemite and it gives you the option of the old Stars, Hearts, or both.  I just went back to Stars...one click for all my library songs.
[image: iTunes 12.2 preferences]

Answer (score 1):

Changed again, or possibly back, in iOS 9.3:  http://www.mcelhearn.com/how-to-rate-songs-in-the-ios-9-3-music-app/